# Avoid template instantiation for different char array sizes

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a simple variadic template code to write argument to a stream:

```
#include <iostream>

void tostream(std::ostream& os) {
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void tostream(std::ostream& os, const T& v, const Args&... args) {
    os << v;
    tostream(os, args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& os, const Args&... args) {
    tostream(os, args...);    
}
```

which I can call with:

```
log(std::cout, "Hello", 3);  
log(std::cout, "Goodbye", 4);
```

I compile this code with Visual Studio 2013 with all optimizations on (Release config) and open the resulting executable with IDA Disassembler.
What I see is that the compiler instantiated two copies of the `log()` function. One that takes `const char[6], int` and one that takes `const char[8], int`.
This is also apparent in the debugger when stepping into these functions and watching the call-stack window.
The two functions are identical other than their signature.

Is there a way to convince the compiler that these two functions should actually be one function which takes `const char*, int` and not two functions?

This is an issue for me since I have hundreds of these function instantiations bloating the size of my executable, most of which could have been avoided.
There will still be many instantiations to the function, for the different combinations of arguments, but there would be a lot less of them since I only have very few possible argument combinations.

One thing that would solve this would be to call the function like so:

```
log(cout, (const char*)"Hello", 3);  
log(cout, (const char*)"Goodbye", 4);
```

But this is unacceptable since it would clutter the code greatly.

Comment: Not really an answer, but did you try hinting the compiler that it may want to `inline` the function calls? Or maybe even forcing it to?

Comment: Are you sure they are identical, that the size isn't used anywhere?  Comdat folding should cause identical implementations to be turned into a single implementation.

Comment: You've been here _six years_, yet you're still writing tags in all your titles? :sadface:

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I shouldn't be?

Comment: @shoosh: Did you not spot that hardly anyone else does it and when they do the title gets edited? We already have a tags system and, unlike your title prefixes, it is semantic and indexed.

Comment: Anyway, I would have thought there'd be a dupe for this good question, but I can't find one.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit There are occasionally questions that do that, even right now in the front page. I wasn't aware this is a rule and personally it helps me browse the front page.

Comment: @shoosh: Well please stop. Yes there are a few "even right now in the front page". Unfortunately most of us have real lives as well as time to spend on volunteer editorial duties.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I would gladly, in case this is actually a globally mandated style guide and not just your personal preference.

Comment: [Should questions include tags in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/200803) -- as for comdat, the recursion passes limitation might limit the ability to sweep away the duplicate functions.  On the first pass, the `<<` gets folded.  On second pass, the `tostream` gets folded.  `log` would be eliminated if you added another comdat folding pass I'd guess?

Answer (score 6):

```
 template<class T>
 using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;

 template<typename... Args>
 void log(ostream& os, const Args&... args) {
   tostream(os, decay_t<Args>(args)...);    
 }
```

will manually decay your arguments before passing them `tostream`.  This will convert functions to function pointers, array references into pointers, etc.

This could cause some spurious copies.  For primitive types, no problem, but is wasteful for `std::string` and the like.  So a narrower solution:

```
template<class T>
struct array_to_ptr {
  using type=T;
};
template<class T, size_t N>
struct array_to_ptr<T(&)[N]> {
  using type=T*;
};
template<class T>
using array_to_ptr_t=typename array_to_ptr<T>::type;

template<typename... Args>
void log(ostream& os, const Args&... args) {
  tostream(os, array_to_ptr_t<Args const&>(args)...);    
}
```

which will only do it for arrays.

Note that distinct implementations of `log` may still exist, but not of `tostream`.  The distinct implementations of `log` should be eliminated by comdat folding and/or inlining of `log`, and possibly eliminating the recursion requirement (to notice it is foldable) will make it easier.

Finally, this may be useful:

```
template<typename... Args>
void tostream(std::ostream& os, const Args&... args) {
  using expand=int[];
  (void)expand{0,
    ((os << args),void(),0)...
  };
}
```

which does a direct expansion without recursion on the arguments in one function.  Your compiler should be smart enough to figure out that the implied array of `0`s is useless, and even if not that is little overhead compared to io.

Comment: Surely if we want to eliminate extra template instantiations, a good candidate is to use a single pack expansion instead of recursion?

Comment: @T.C. *nod*.  Added an `int[]` expand.  Too bad we aren't C++1z, fold expressions are tasty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a proper solution for you but, in terms of workarounds, would the following be sufficiently less "clutter" for you?

```
log(cout, +"Hello", 3);  
log(cout, +"Goodbye", 4);
```

I appreciate that you still need your users to remember to do this, which sucks.